# Update ComboBox Once item is selected

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm lost and could really use some help. I'm trying to update a combo box with a list of column names from a csv file (selected by the open file button, and string input into textbox).

```
Function GetFileName($initialDirectory)
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $OpenFileDialog.multiselect = $false
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
}

Function GetColumnsFromFile
{
    Param ($fileWithPath)

    [string]$csvFileColumnTitles = Get-Content $fileWithPath -totalcount 1

    [String[]]$csvFileColumnTitles = ($csvFileColumnTitles -replace ",", "|").Trim()
    [String[]]$csvFileColumnTitles = ($csvFileColumnTitles -replace "`"", "").Trim()
    [String[]]$listOfColumnTitles = $csvFileColumnTitles.Split('|',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

    return $listOfColumnTitles
}

Function GUIBox
{
    # Creates GUI Box In Memory
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.drawing
    $Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Width = '1200'
    $Form.Height = '800'

    # TabControl
    $TabControl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
    $TabControl.Name = "TabControl"
    $TabControl.TabIndex = 4
    $TabControl.SelectedIndex = 0
    $TabControl.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 0
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 50
    $TabControl.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 685
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 1184
    $TabControl.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Form.Controls.Add($TabControl)

    # Test 1 Tab
    $Test1_Tab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
    $Test1_Tab.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Test1_Tab.Name = "Test 1"
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 0
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 50
    $Test1_Tab.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 685
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 1184
    $Test1_Tab.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Test1_Tab.TabIndex = 1
    $Test1_Tab.Text = "Test 1"
    $Test1_Tab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $TabControl.Controls.Add($Test1_Tab)

    # Open File Label
    $SelectSourceFile_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $SelectSourceFile_Label.Location = "10, 30"
    $SelectSourceFile_Label.Name = "label"
    $SelectSourceFile_Label.Size = "120, 20"
    $SelectSourceFile_Label.TabIndex = 3
    $SelectSourceFile_Label.Text = "Select Source File"
    $Test1_Tab.Controls.Add($SelectSourceFile_Label)

    # Open File Textbox
    $SelectSourceFile_Textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $SelectSourceFile_Textbox.Location = '10, 50'
    $SelectSourceFile_Textbox.Size = '200, 20'
    $SelectSourceFile_Textbox.TabIndex = 3
    $SelectSourceFile_Textbox.Text = $Test1_FileInput_Textbox_String
    $Test1_Tab.Controls.Add($SelectSourceFile_Textbox)

    # Open File Button
    $SelectSourceFile_Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $SelectSourceFile_Button.DialogResult = 'None'
    $SelectSourceFile_Button.Location = '210, 50'
    $SelectSourceFile_Button.Name = 'Open File Button'
    $SelectSourceFile_Button.Size = '75, 25'
    $SelectSourceFile_Button.TabIndex = 3
    $SelectSourceFile_Button.Text = 'Open File'
    $SelectSourceFile_Button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
    $SelectSourceFile_Button_Click = {$SelectSourceFile_Textbox.Text = GetFileName}
    $SelectSourceFile_Button.add_Click($SelectSourceFile_Button_Click)
    $Test1_Tab.Controls.Add($SelectSourceFile_Button)

    # Select Open File Columns Label
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Label.Location = "10, 90"
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Label.Name = "label"
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Label.Size = "150, 20"
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Label.TabIndex = 3
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Label.Text = "Select Source File Column"
    $Test1_Tab.Controls.Add($SelectSourceFileColumn_Label)

    # Select Open File Columns Dropdown
    [String[]]$ColumnList = GetColumnsFromFile 'C:\Scripts\Tests\1Project\Test.csv'
    Write-Host '$ColumnList =' $ColumnList
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Dropdown = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Dropdown.FormattingEnabled = $True
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Dropdown.Location = '10, 110'
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Dropdown.Name = 'File Column'
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Dropdown.Size = '200, 20'
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Dropdown.TabIndex = 3
    $SelectSourceFileColumn_Dropdown.Height = 30
    $Test1_Tab.Controls.Add($SelectSourceFileColumn_Dropdown)

    ## Display GUI Box ##
    $Form.ShowDialog()
}

GUIBox
```

The csv file...

```
"ColumnOne","ColumnTwo","ColumnThree"
"ColumnOneValueOne","ColumnTwoValueOne","ColumnThreeValueOne"
"ColumnOneValueTwo","ColumnTwoValueTwo","ColumnThreeValueTwo"
"ColumnOneValueThree","ColumnTwoValueThree","ColumnThreeValueThree"
```

So in the powershell window, we can see it is able to print the 3 column names. I know if I try this line `[String[]]$ColumnList = GetColumnsFromFile $SelectSourceFile_Textbox.Text` (replacing line 110), it will error out (because it will iterate through this line, before the user has a chance to input the selected file). So how would I update the combobox (with column names from the csv file) after the user has input their csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is to use the button click to show the `FolderBrowserDialog` and if you get a filename from it, get the headings and add each one to the combobox.

You can use the same technique to populate the ComboBox when the user types into the textbox by creating a `TextChanged` event.

[image: ComboBox]

I got this to work using the following code:

```
function GUIBox {

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Import the Assemblies
    #----------------------------------------------
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.ServiceProcess, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    #endregion Import Assemblies

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Objects
    #----------------------------------------------
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
    $textbox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
    $combobox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'
    $buttonLoadCsv = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    # User Generated Script
    #----------------------------------------------

    function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
    {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

        $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
        $OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
        $OpenFileDialog.multiselect = $false
        $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
        return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
    }

    $form1_Load={
        #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here

    }

    $buttonLoadCsv_Click={
        #TODO: Place custom script here

        $file = Get-FileName -initialDirectory $env:USERPROFILE

        if ($file)
        {
            $textbox1.Text = $file

            try
            {
                $headers = Import-Csv -Path $file | Get-Member | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique
                Write-Host ($headers | Out-String)
                $combobox1.Items.Clear()
                foreach($header in $headers)
                {
                    $combobox1.Items.Add($header)
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Warning -Message "The following error occured while trying to get the headings for csv file $file`: $($_.Exception.Message)"
            }
        }
    }

    # --End User Generated Script--
    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Events
    #----------------------------------------------

    $Form_StateCorrection_Load=
    {
        #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    $Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
    {
        #Remove all event handlers from the controls
        try
        {
            $buttonLoadCsv.remove_Click($buttonLoadCsv_Click)
            $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
            $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
            $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
        }
        catch [Exception]
        { }
    }
    #endregion Generated Events

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    #----------------------------------------------
    $form1.SuspendLayout()
    #
    # form1
    #
    $form1.Controls.Add($textbox1)
    $form1.Controls.Add($combobox1)
    $form1.Controls.Add($buttonLoadCsv)
    $form1.ClientSize = '390, 76'
    $form1.Name = 'form1'
    $form1.Text = 'Form'
    $form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
    #
    # textbox1
    #
    $textbox1.Location = '12, 14'
    $textbox1.Name = 'textbox1'
    $textbox1.Size = '284, 20'
    $textbox1.TabIndex = 2
    #
    # combobox1
    #
    $combobox1.DropDownStyle = 'DropDownList'
    $combobox1.FormattingEnabled = $True
    $combobox1.Location = '12, 40'
    $combobox1.Name = 'combobox1'
    $combobox1.Size = '284, 21'
    $combobox1.TabIndex = 1
    #
    # buttonLoadCsv
    #
    $buttonLoadCsv.Location = '302, 12'
    $buttonLoadCsv.Name = 'buttonLoadCsv'
    $buttonLoadCsv.Size = '75, 49'
    $buttonLoadCsv.TabIndex = 0
    $buttonLoadCsv.Text = 'Load Csv'
    $buttonLoadCsv.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonLoadCsv.add_Click($buttonLoadCsv_Click)
    $form1.ResumeLayout()
    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #----------------------------------------------

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
    #Clean up the control events
    $form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    #Show the Form
    return $form1.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

#Call the form
GUIBox | Out-Null
```